# plotting PCA and kmeans clustering output in scatter plot whilst colouring according to date with gradient legend in python matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, k-means, pca

I'd like to add a gradient legend based on the date of the points in the cluster. I've already applied PCA and clustered the data. Also how to test the performance.

I have this [no legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T72hR.png)
I want something with a legend like this [with legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvw5Z.png)

I'm trying to predict when wells will fail.

```py
from matplotlib import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, normalize
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import Kmeans

ccData = pd.read_csv("/Users/frun/Desktop/flum/E-43.csv", index_col=0)
print("Rows :", ccData.shape[0])
print("Columns :", ccData.shape[1])
ccData.drop(ccData.columns[ccData.columns.str.contains('unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True) # drop unnamed column

#Standardize and Normalize
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_ccData = scaler.fit_transform(ccData)
norm_ccData = normalize(scaled_ccData)

#PCA
pca = PCA()
pca.fit(norm_ccData)

n_components = 2
pca_final = PCA(n_components = n_components)
pca_final.fit(norm_ccData)
pca_ccData = pca_final.fit_transform(norm_ccData)

#Kmeans Clustering

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0)
kmeans.fit(pca_ccData)

plt.scatter(pca_ccData[:,0], pca_ccData[:,1],
            c = KMeans(n_clusters = 3).fit_predict(pca_ccData),
            cmap = plt.cm.summer)

plt.xlabel("PC1")
plt.ylabel("PC2")

plt.show()

h = .01

x_min, x_max = pca_ccData[:,0].min() - 1, pca_ccData[:,0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = pca_ccData[:,1].min() - 1, pca_ccData[:,1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

Z = kmeans.predict(np.array(list(zip(xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()))))

Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest',
           extent=(xx.min(), xx.max(), yy.min(), yy.max()),
           cmap=plt.cm.summer,
           aspect='auto', origin='lower')

plt.plot(pca_ccData[:,0], pca_ccData[:,1], 'k.', markersize=2)
a bit of the csv file
```

a bit of the csv file

```
Date ,Frequency ,Avg VSD Current ,Drive Volts ,Intake Pressure ,Discharge Pressure,Intake Temperature ,Motor Temperature ,Vibration x  ,Vibration y  ,SYS Current,
11/13/2015,42,114,338,791.1,961,46.46,32.37,0.077,0.065,11.851,
11/13/2015,42,113,339,791.3,949.2,46.43,32.37,0.063,0.066,11.847,
```

Comment: these variable are not defined:  `StandardScaler`, `normalize`, `PCA`,  `KMeans`... please add the necessary imports or define them so that the code works.

Comment: questions like this are better:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example